# Add new field in nested object firestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) there is code to update the nested object field but there is no code or documentation about how we can add the new field in the nested object?

```
// Assume the document contains:
// {
//   name: "Frank",
//   favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" }
//   age: 12
// }
//
// To update age and favorite color:
db.collection("users").document("frank")
        .update(
                "age", 13,
                "favorites.color", "Red"
        );
```

As you can see here we are updating the `favorites.color` to `Red`, but how we can add the new field `code` in the `favorites` object?

Suppose I want to update the above document as the follows:

```
{
  name: "Frank",
  favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess", code:32 }
  age: 12
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the document does exist, its contents will not be overwritten with the newly provided data if you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document like this:

```
Map<String, Object> favorites = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> favorite = new HashMap<>();
favorite.put("code", 32);
favorites.put("favorites", favorite);
rootRef.collection("users").document("frank").set(favorites, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: The second argument of the `set()` method is used to tell Firebase that you don't want to override that object instead you want to update it. Every node in a NoSQL database is a `Map` and in case of a `Map`, when using the `set()` method, it replaces the old value with the new one. So using this argument you'll avoid overrding that object.

Comment: How I can remove the field? as how I can remove the age from the above document?

Comment: You need to use: `favorite.put("age", FieldValue.delete());`.

Comment: Can you send me documentation link? from where you are getting these extension methods?

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data).